# How to display a full-width grid of images that resizes and flows with the browser window with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to display a set of images in a grid, and would like to reproduce the effect of the album grid view in iTunes with pure CSS, if possible.

Desired functionality (video: http://quick.as/17l3sdgr):

1. The images should be displayed in a grid with some padding, filling the browser width.
2. When the window is resized, the images & padding shrink until some minimum img width (let's say 150px).
3. Then the one image is pushed to the next row, and the images become bigger until window width is decreased again.

I know this is possible with javascript, but CSS would provide better performance. Is it possible?

Edit: I recorded a screencast to show the functionality from iTunes: http://quick.as/17l3sdgr

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a reference of what you are trying to achieve.
We have support for animations and transitions in CSS3.

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/gawcP/)?

Comment: You can look at [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) in combination with an [imagesLoaded](http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html).

Comment: @tewathia doesn't achieve step 2

Comment: @ShridharGupta I know, it's an old fiddle that I once made to demonstrate Responsive Design to someone. You'll have to style the div tags(giving `width` in percentage and `min-width` in pixels) inside the media queries to get the exact behaviour you want

Comment: Starting a bounty and accept an answer after minutes ...!? And also Google will give you many arguments why e.g. `inline-block` is much more preferable than `float`. But it's all up to you ...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shridhargupta/k4xMX/)**

Cooluhuru's answer set me in the right direction.

**Starting with Cooluhuru's Answer:**

```
img
{
    float:left;
    width : 31%;
    padding : 1%;
    max-width: 150px;
    min-width : 100px;
}
```

Which floats the images in a grid pattern, with an percentage based padding. max-width and min-width are required.

**Next Steps:**

Now, we add media queries on the points where the image overflows to the next line (or even before, but then the images won't go to max-width).

With 200x200px images, this was at (464px,690px,860px,1040px). Breakpoints will depend on the image width, so this will only work for same size-width images.

Next, for each breakpoint only the image width % needs to be adjusted, to allow for the images to fill the row in it's smallest media-query state, and be small enough that the images can grow.

Notes:

1. It'll be best to have a fixed padding, since the padding just keeps getting more and more as the window gets bigger.

Comment: Adapting the images min-width & max-width to 50px & 80px, I can observe the effect you are looking for. BTW, thanks for the fiddle:)

Comment: Your JS Fiddle link is broken

Answer (score 2):

Try this (untested)

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YZ2Bb/2/)

CSS :

```
img{
  float:left;
  width : 10%;
  padding : 1%;
  max-width : 150px;
  min-width : 50px;
}
```

HTML :

```
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
<img src="yourimage.jpg" />
```

Comment: this one is very close, it resizes then pushes to the next line, but doesn't resize the images to fit the newly available space on the right.

Comment: Thank you! This set me in the right direction. See my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

just use a table for that.
you shouldn't use tables for layouting. but you should use tables for tables ;)

so just place all your stuff into a table. that's realy easy.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingOrangeReal/200x200_OilPaintingOrangeReal_609fc3f644b74122ba5719f9e3255d2f.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingRed/200x200_OilPaintingRed_320c459d9c874e03b8b5c7daab8eb69d.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingGreen/200x200_OilPaintingGreen_c105d0d423204591937169f2ebe630eb.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingBlue/200x200_OilPaintingBlue_37b898bfa1e8469cba9c5ad5af118870.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingOrangeReal/200x200_OilPaintingOrangeReal_609fc3f644b74122ba5719f9e3255d2f.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingRed/200x200_OilPaintingRed_320c459d9c874e03b8b5c7daab8eb69d.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingGreen/200x200_OilPaintingGreen_c105d0d423204591937169f2ebe630eb.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingBlue/200x200_OilPaintingBlue_37b898bfa1e8469cba9c5ad5af118870.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingOrangeReal/200x200_OilPaintingOrangeReal_609fc3f644b74122ba5719f9e3255d2f.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingRed/200x200_OilPaintingRed_320c459d9c874e03b8b5c7daab8eb69d.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingGreen/200x200_OilPaintingGreen_c105d0d423204591937169f2ebe630eb.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingBlue/200x200_OilPaintingBlue_37b898bfa1e8469cba9c5ad5af118870.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingOrangeReal/200x200_OilPaintingOrangeReal_609fc3f644b74122ba5719f9e3255d2f.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingRed/200x200_OilPaintingRed_320c459d9c874e03b8b5c7daab8eb69d.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingGreen/200x200_OilPaintingGreen_c105d0d423204591937169f2ebe630eb.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingBlue/200x200_OilPaintingBlue_37b898bfa1e8469cba9c5ad5af118870.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Valtos/X3tTh/

Comment: This achieves the first two steps, but doesn't push images to the next row when they're too small.

Comment: Semantically one should use `<table>` for tabular data. A bunch of images are certainly no tabular data. To display them **like** table elements there are the different values (table, table-row, table-cell) for the display property in CSS.

Comment: Tables are meant for table data, not images. You can do this by visiting this tutorial. https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong. But I propose my answer [here](http://jsfiddle.net/X3tTh/2/). I might have borrowed someone else's fiddle. Sorry for that. You can drag the slider to see the effect to responsiveness due to utilization of Bootstrap on the images.

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">                
            <a href="#"><img src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/img/example-sites/gathercontent.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4 style="text-align:center;">Image Thumbnail 1</h4>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">                
            <a href="#"><img src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/img/example-sites/soundready.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4 style="text-align:center;">Image Thumbnail 2</h4>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">                
            <a href="#"><img src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/img/example-sites/soundready.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4 style="text-align:center;">Image Thumbnail 3</h4>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly what bootstrap was made for. You can define number of columns to take at any given resolution or you can write your own media queries. Would you like me to create another Fiddle for the effect you wanted?

Comment: Maybe this will do: http://jsfiddle.net/X3tTh/17. Drag the slider to see the effect. I do not think there are any other solution other than hitting breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the [**CSS Flexible Box Layout Module**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) is meant for!

Unfortunately especially Firefox does not (yet) support the [**‘flex-wrap’ property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-wrap-property), which you would need in your case.

So to do it "right" only with CSS, the answer is, you have to wait for better browser support!

In the meanwhile you can get close to your desired behaviour by using `display: inline-block` for your images in conjunction with media queries to adjust the image sizes.